# Is there a smooth distance-persaving bijection between two simple curves with same length?

Tags: analysis, differential-geometry, curves

If $M,N \subset \mathbb R^n$ are two simple curves with same length $L[M]=L[N]<\infty$, is there a smooth bijection $F: M \to N$ so that for every parametrized curve $\gamma$ in $M$ $$L[\gamma]=L[F\circ \gamma]$$ holds?

Comment: Yes. Parametrize each curve by arc length. Fix $m$ in $M$ and $n$ in $N$; map $m$ to $n$, then use the arc length parametrizations in the obvious way to map $M$ to $N$.

Comment: Sorry, I do not think I really get it. If $\gamma:I \to M$ is parametrized by arc length and $\beta:J \to N$ is parametrized by arc length, then $F: M\to N$ with $\gamma(m) \mapsto \beta(m)$ is bijective and distance-persaving? If this is the answer: can I assume $I=J$?

Comment: Yes, that's the idea. :) You can assume $I = J$ because $M$ and $N$ have the same arc length.

Comment: Okay, nice. So if $\alpha:[a,b]\to M$ is a curve in M now. How can I calculate that $L[F \circ \alpha]=L[\alpha]$? I know that $L[F\circ \alpha]=\int\limits_a^b ||(F \circ \alpha (t) )'||dt$ but I do not see how I can compute this.

Comment: In arc length coordinates, $F$ is the identity map (!), so by the chain rule,$$L[F \circ \alpha] = \int_{a}^{f} \|(F \circ \alpha)'(t)\|\, dt = \int_{a}^{b} \|\alpha'(t)\|\, dt = L[\alpha].$$

Comment: What does your $f$ mean? Why does $F$ being the identity in the $arc length$ coordinates imply the above equality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\Reals}{\mathbf{R}}$Just so this has an answer: Conceptually, $M$ and $N$ are isometric to a circle of fixed circumference, hence isometric to each other, and an isometry $F:M \to N$ has the desired property.

In more detail, let $\ell = L[M] = L[N]$ be the common lengths of $M$ and $N$. Pick a point $m$ in $M$ arbitrarily and an arc length parametrization $\mu:[0, \ell] \to M$ such that $\mu(0) = \mu(\ell) = m$. Extending $\mu$ by periodicity defines an isometry $\mu:\Reals/\ell\mathbf{Z} \to M$.

Similarly, if $n$ is an arbitrary point of $N$ and $\nu:[0, \ell] \to N$ is an arc length parametrization with $\nu(0) = \nu(\ell) = n$, then the periodic extension of $\nu$ defines an isometry $\nu:\Reals/\ell\mathbf{Z} \to N$.

The mapping $F = \nu \circ \mu^{-1}:M \to N$, defined by $F\bigl(\mu(t)\bigr) = \nu(t)$ for $t$ real, is therefore a composition of isometries, hence an isometry.

If $\gamma:I \to M$ is a curve, then $\|(F \circ \gamma)'\| = \|\gamma'\|$ because $F$ is an isometry, so $L[F \circ \gamma] = L[\gamma]$.